# How do I make buttons moved through css pushable when z-index doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, button, z-index

I have two buttons and a `<select>` like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; bottom: +93; margin-left: 200px;">
  <button name="" value="">Bypass</button>
  <button name="open" value="n">Bypass</button>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; bottom: +115px; font-size: 13px; margin-left: -341px;">Amount: <select name="onelink"><option value="0">Select</option><option value="1">1</option></select></div>
```

Right now, I cant click the buttons, only the `<select>`, If I add `z-index: 1;` to the buttons, I cant click the `<select>` anymore. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you move the button so drastically in general?